# Ajax does not send the data to my php file

Tags: php, ajax

I try to send my data to php file but does not work.
This my ajax file

```
 var artistIds = new Array();

    $(".p16 input:checked").each(function(){
        artistIds.push($(this).attr('id'));
    });


   $.post('/json/crewonly/deleteDataAjax2', { artistIds: artistIds },function(response){
        if(response == 'ok')
            alert('dolu');
        elseif (response == 'error')
            alert('bos');
    });
```

and this is  my php

```
public function deleteDataAjax2() {

        extract($_POST);

        if (isset($artistIds))
            $this->sendJSONResponse('ok');
        else
            $this->sendJSONResponse('error');
    }
```

However, my artistIds in php side is null. Why ?

Comment: Add `var_dump($_POST)` to your `deleteDataAjax2` to see exactly what you're getting.

Comment: What does `sendJSONResponse` echo?

Comment: [How to pass a Javascript Array via JQuery Post so that all its contents are accessible via the PHP $_POST array?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571646/how-to-pass-a-javascript-array-via-jquery-post-so-that-all-its-contents-are-acce

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass an array without serializing the values first.

See: [How to send js array via ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692991/how-to-send-js-array-via-ajax)

Comment: This is wrong.  Passing `{IDs: [1,2,3]}` to `$.post` will send `IDs[]=1&IDs[]=2&IDs[]=3` as the query string, thus making it an array when read by PHP.

Comment: Please see => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571646/how-to-pass-a-javascript-array-via-jquery-post-so-that-all-its-contents-are-acce